# Jersey exception mapper is not being invoked from Filter class

Tags: scala, rest, guice, rest-client, jersey-1.0

I have one Jersey(version 1.19) Exception Mapper class to send custom error to rest client.

```
@Provider
class GenericExceptionMapper extends ExceptionMapper[Exception] {

  private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[GenericExceptionMapper])

  override def toResponse(exception: Exception): Response = {
    exception match {
      case e: IllegalArgumentException => responseWithError(e, 400, () => logger.warn("Illegal argument exception" + e.getMessage))
      case e: WebApplicationException => e.getResponse
      case e => responseWithError(e, 500, () => logger.error("Exception: " + e.getMessage, e))
    }
  }

  private def responseWithError[T](e: Exception, statusCode: Int, fn: () => Unit) : Response = {
    fn()
    Response.status(statusCode).`type`(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).entity(e.getMessage).build()
  }
}
```

When I am throwing IllegalArgumentException from Filter class for any mandatory header is missing, the GenericExceptionMapper class is not being invoked. However when any exception is thrown from the resource class(i.e. having @Path annotation), the GenericExceptionMapper is being invoked.

Is there any configuration is missing?

Please note, I have extended PackagesResourceConfig class of Jersey package for package scanning.

Comment: Is the filter even being hit?

Comment: yes, those header validation inside filter are working.